# Jenkins-bitbucket ( Difference between Git-bash/Openssh and WIndows prompt/pageant )

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I have tried hard to setup Jenkins Jobs to connect to bitbucket. It is a windows machine.

1. I have generated a SSH key pair and added an SSH Key to my Bitbucket.
2. I have loaded the private key like this using Git-bash

> $ ssh-add -l
>   2048 SHA256:iB//Q8zoeAtGBRrPDnK9yicrANAJs80Fx9tNZSRgHOY /d/jenkins/jenkins_bitbucket (RSA)

After that this command ran without showing an error.

> $ git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:ilppoc/security.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

The result of this command is also fine.

> ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
>
> logged in as ilppoc.
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is
>   disabled. debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype
>   exit-status reply 0 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels
>   1 Transferred: sent 3112, received 1728 bytes, in 0.5 seconds Bytes
>   per second: sent 5867.3, received 3257.9 debug1: Exit status 0

But my Windows prompt isn't recognizing the key.

> *C:\Windows\system32>git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:ilppoc/security.git   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.   Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights   and the repository exists.*

So I converted the OpenSSH private key to Putty .ppk and loaded it manually using pageant. I can see it in the pageant window.

It still doesn't help. As a consequence my Jenkins job fails because as I mentioned this command doesn't run from the windows prompt.

> D:\testbitbucketclone\security>git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org
>   :ilppoc/security.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

What is wrong here ?

Additionally known_hosts is filled up. Git-bash works and Windows prompt doesn't ?

How should I fix this ?

Edit :
The exact error in Jenkins is this.

> Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch
>   --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:ilppoc/security.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a newer version of git for Windows, you might get useful diagnostic information from the commands (from the Windows command prompt):

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv
git clone git@bitbucket.org:ilppoc/security.git
```

That will provide detailed debugging information about ssh as used by git.

If you prefer to run that from the Windows "Git Bash" shell, then the command is:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@bitbucket.org:ilppoc/security.git
```

Comment: I changed the name of my key to id_rsa because the verbose switch showed me it is searching for that. Now I am authenticated from Windows prompt. But Jenkins has the same error.

Comment: I had to change the user that is running Jenkins to make this work.